# Why these two methods to get the interest earned on recurring deposits return different results?

Tags: calculus, rounding-error

Suppose that at the beginning of each month I make a deposit of 100 dollars on an account with a 1% monthly rate. I want to calculate the earned interest after 6 months.

**Method 1**

`End of month    Earned Interest
1               1            (100*0.01)
2               2.01         ((200 + 1)*0.01)
3               3.0201       ((300 + 2.01)*0.01)
4               4.030201     ((400 + 3.0201)*0.01)
5               5.04030201   ((500 + 4.030201)*0.01)
6               6.0504030201 ((600 + 5.04030201)*0.01)`

Total earned interest after 6 months:
21.1510060301

**Method 2**

`End of month   Account Balance (invested + interests)
1              101            (100*1.01)
2              203.01         ((101+100)*1.01)
3              306.0401       ((203.01+100)*1.01)
4              410.100501     ((306.0401+100)*1.01)
5              515.20150601   ((410.100501+100)*1.01)
6              621.3535210701 ((515.20150601+100)*1.01)`

Total earned interest after 6 months:
21.3535210701  (621.3535210701 - 600)

**Why the difference?**

With the second method, more than 20 cents more are earned.
I thought the difference could be because of rounding issues, but I've even tried to write a Clojure program using its [Ratio type](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#_ratio) and the differences are the same:

211510060301/10000000000  (method 1)
213535210701/10000000000  (method 2)

So, how is the difference explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method 1 is incorrect. You forgot to add the first dollar of interest to the amount on which interest was calcuated in month 3 (and the same error is repeated thereafter). Here is the correct version:

```
End of month    Earned Interest
1               1            (100*0.01)
2               2.01         ((200 + 1)*0.01)
3               3.0301       ((300 + 1+2.01)*0.01)
```

A better table might have a column for the cumulative interest and account balance:

```
End of month   Interest in that month    Cumulative interest   Account balance before interest
1               1            (100*0.01)           1                 100
2               2.01         (201*0.01)           3.01              201
3               3.0301       (303.01*0.01)        6.0401            303.01
```